# Save state for DropDownList after post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

i have form with one **textbox** and **dropdownlist**

```
<%=Html.TextBox("Name")%>
<%=Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "Enter name")%>
```

<%=Html.DropDownList("Not Selected", "DomainID", ViewData["DomainID"])%>

I select value from drop **downlist** but dont fill name, im getting validation for **textbox** and then i need select value from **dropdown** again, of course with **textbox** it works but what can i do with **list**??

Answer (score 2):

I assume that ViewData["DomainID"] is a SelectList?  The constructor for SelectList takes a selectedValue object.  Use that to pass the selected value in to your select list in the post action.

Comment: Did but still dont want select:
ViewData["DomainID"] = new SelectList(commonService.GetDomains(), "ID", "Name", (item.Domain == null ? 0 : item.Domain.ID));